# How to locate objects based on specific motion in video using computer vision?

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, opticalflow

I am working on a problem where I have to track some machine usage of some surveillance video(stock example video).

[image]

My problem is what kind of modern Machine learning techniques or traditional computer vision methods that can I use, I don't want to use a single frame input source model (like object recognition on frame) because there are lots of occlusions & also is hard to recognize some machine objects because of side viewpoint ,so I have to use uniform motions of machine data from input video.